# Unable to upload CSV file using google analytics API in C#

Tags: c#, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to upload a CSV file using google analytics api and it gives me a status failed.
The error that I'm getting is variable is null: parameter  name base uri

I have given the permissions for google analytics api in developer console and I'm using service account to generate the key and the id's.

This is my code snippet

```
        const string serviceAccountEmail = "716698526626-6s61a3tbe1m5mofo9@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
        const string serviceAccountPKCSP12FilePath = @"C:\SVN\GAPforInboundandWeb-1f6bfb.p12";
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(serviceAccountPKCSP12FilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
            {
                Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics }
            }.FromCertificate(certificate));
        var service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "GAPforInboundandWeb"
        });

        FileStream realCsv = new FileStream("c:\\real.csv", FileMode.Open);
        // Create the service.


        try
        {
            var upload = service.Management.DailyUploads.Upload("50288725", "UA-50288725-1", "Oy_0JTPvRGCB3Vg5OKVIMQ",
                "2014-09-22", 1, ManagementResource.DailyUploadsResource.UploadMediaUpload.TypeEnum.Cost, realCsv,
                "application/octet-stream");
            upload.Reset = true;
            var res = upload.Upload();
            res.BytesSent.ToString();
            res.Status.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same problem. In my case, its a wrong DataSourceId.
Try this:

```
 const string serviceAccountEmail = "716698526626-6s61a3tbe1m5mofo9@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
    const string serviceAccountPKCSP12FilePath = @"C:\SVN\GAPforInboundandWeb-1f6bfb.p12";
    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(serviceAccountPKCSP12FilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

    ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
        new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
        {
            Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics }
        }.FromCertificate(certificate));
    var service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "GAPforInboundandWeb"
    });

    FileStream realCsv = new FileStream("c:\\real.csv", FileMode.Open);
    // Create the service.


    try
    {
        var dataSource = srv.Management.CustomDataSources.List(AccountId, WebId).Execute();
        var strDataSourceId = "Oy_0JTPvRGCB3Vg5OKVIMQ";
        if(dataSource!=null && dataSource.Items.Length>0)
          strDataSourceId =dataSource.Items[0].Id;
        var upload = service.Management.DailyUploads.Upload("50288725", "UA-50288725-1", strDataSourceId,
            "2014-09-22", 1, ManagementResource.DailyUploadsResource.UploadMediaUpload.TypeEnum.Cost, realCsv,
            "application/octet-stream");
        upload.Reset = true;
        var res = upload.Upload();
        res.BytesSent.ToString();
        res.Status.ToString();
    }
```

Use List methods on service.Management.CustomDataSources and service.Management.Uploads in this order for check your config.